# Clearing eof bit not working with while loop

Tags: c++, eof, getline

I have a program I'm trying to write that constantly monitors a log file and outputs specific items into a new file.

I'm using essentially.

```
for (int i = 1; i < y; i ++)
    getline(read, line); // skips to the last known end

while (getline(read, line))
{
cout << line;
}

read.clear();
```

I also keep track of the line I'm on just using the increment operator on a variable. At the end of the file I clear the eof bit and seek to the last line I was on. From using the debugger it seems that it works. I retrieve the next line in the file as its being written but when I call back to my `while (getline(read,line));` it skips going through the while loop, why is that?

- program reads the last line in the file.
- Sleeps for 5 minutes.
- The input file has had new lines added to it from a third party.
- After the sleep it wakes up and goes back to the while loop.
- It successfully retrieves the new lines from the input. But fails to
  enter the while loop again

Comment: `seekg(y)` seeks to the byte offset `y`, not to the line number `y`. You need to use `tellg()` and remember the byte offset of the line you want, so you can return to it later.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh, I was mistaken. I use a for loop to skip through the getline to the end. I have updated the post. I was using seekg for nothing.

Comment: Is there a rewind (seek to the start) in there somewhere? Your code makes no sense without one.

Comment: You'll probably get better results trying to read from a file that's being actively written to by another process by using `open()` and `read()` or `pread()`.  It's actually not an easy problem to solve, and putting layers of abstraction and buffering between your code and the file, such as with a C++ `istream`, isn't likely to work very well.  As you're finding out.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I believe since I never close the input stream, it reserves the current line it is on, it only does the iteration when the program ends and is restarted, the line it was on is also stored in the file and is received on start up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `std::getline()` at the end of a file both `std::iostate::eofbit` and `std::iostate::failbit` are set. In fact, it is `std::iostate::failbit` which causes the loop to exit. You'll need to clear both of these flags prior to any seek.

For a system which needs to use IOStreams I would actually not bother reading the leading lines but merely wait a bit, clear the flags, and try again. The main issue is detecting whether a complete line is read which could be done by simply reading individual characters, e.g., using `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`.

Otherwise I'd look for a system API which provide some sort of indication that new data is available on a file. Older system generally don't provide such facilities but newer system generally have some event-based interface which can be used to get hold of newly available data. The advantage is normally that the processes doesn't poll for new data but idly waits until it gets notified about new data. I haven't used it myself but it seems [libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/) does this sort of operations in a somewhat platform-independent form.